# jekyll rss feed on heroku

Tags: heroku, rss, jekyll

I currently have a running jekyll set up on heroku and use the following `procfile`:

```
web: jekyll serve --no-watch --port $PORT --host 0.0.0.0
```

I think the issue is somewhere here, but my rss feed xml returns this and obviously doesn't have the domain name that I need to set links.

[image]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to handle this is to bundle jekyll inside Rack. http://rack.github.io/

You can do this by creating a `config.ru` and a Rake task that handles the build

Rakefile:

```
namespace :assets do
  task :precompile do
    puts `bundle exec jekyll build`
  end
end
```

config.ru:

```
require 'rack/contrib/try_static'
require 'rack/contrib/not_found'

    use Rack::TryStatic,
      :root => "_site",
      :urls => %w[/],
      :try  => ['index.html', '/index.html']

    run Rack::NotFound.new('_site/404.html')
```